# Windows XP app in a container on Ubuntu

Tags: containers

I have an application that manages a slide scanner on a system with Windows XP via USB port.
Now I want to dismiss this system, it's very old.
I'm using a notebook equipped with Ubuntu Studio.
My question is: is it possible to use a container to run this XP application on Ubuntu or I need a virtual machine with Windows XP?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: You need virtual machine.. containers doesn't support UI mostly except its X11